# Overlapping content when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, wordpress, position, css-float, word-wrap

This is my first time posting to the forum and I'm by no means a web developer but I have been learning as I go.

The problem I'm having with is http://www.audiofactory.co.uk.

On some pages there are music players. Created using a Wordpress plugin. 
See pages below for examples.

```
-services/audio-books/

-services/voiceovers/

-services/voicereels/

-/services/radiocontent/

-/our-team/voice-talent/
```

I have edited some CSS styles for each player to give it a specific width for a given page.

```
/* ===== "voicetalent" ===== */     
.voicetalent div.playlist-colour { position:absolute; height:115px }        
.voicetalent div.playlist-wrap-MI ul { position:static; height:115px }

/* ===== "voicereels" ===== */  
.voicereels div.playlist-colour { position:absolute; height:207px }     
.voicereels div.playlist-wrap-MI ul { position:static; height:207px }

/* ===== "audiobooks" ===== */  

.audiobooks div.playlist-colour { position:absolute; height:251px  }        
.audiobooks div.playlist-wrap-MI ul { position:static; height:251px  }
```

If you take a look at http://www.audiofactory.co.uk/services/audio-books/
you can see that when you resize the browser window the player does not resize as you would expect and overlaps the image on the left. I'd like the player to auto adjust its width when changing the width of the browser so everything stays relative.

I have spoken to the developer of the music player plugin and he suggested this

> It looks like it's just a markup issue, it would probably work if you float the player as well as the image, either using the 'pos' parameter in the shortcode or by wrapping the shortcode in another floated div of a given width.

As the instructions were not very specific I was a bit unsure of how to implement these suggestions.

I tried wrapping my short code in a `<div>` like so but its probably completely wrong.

```
/* ===== "audiobooks" ===== */  
<div position:float;>
.audiobooks div.playlist-colour { position:absolute; height:251px  }        
.audiobooks div.playlist-wrap-MI ul { position:static; height:251px  }
</div>
```

Any help you could offer would be really appreciated.

Comment: The solution is to take the source and keep cutting bits off of it until you have the smallest possible HTML file that still has the problem. Then publish that.

Answer (score 0):

Floating would be easiest. You'll have to add a clearfix for this to work properly so you can force the floated elements to behave as desired when they stack.

First include this into your main style sheet at a top level (top of the file).

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

In the html for the audiobook you'll have to add the clearfix class as below.

```
<div id="wrapperMI_0" class="clearfix wrap-MI audiobooks nolistbutton nopn">
```

On the div.wrap-MI class in css add:

```
float: left;
width: 48%;
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I've done as you have said.  Adding the clearfix to the style sheet messes up the entire site all sorts of things are moved around.  I did as you said and added it at the top of the file.  I added the clearfix class like so  `/
  div.wrap-MI { border:0; margin:0; background:none; min-width:116px; float: left; width: 48%; /* position||float set in-line! */ /* width set in-line! */ }`  I've added the html like so  `[mp3-jplayer style=<div id="wrapperMI_0" class="clearfix wrap-MI audiobooks nolistbutton nopn" pos="rel-R" tracks=`etc.

Comment: Update I've put the html code inside a div like this  `<div id="wrapperMI_0" class="clearfix wrap-MI>
[mp3-jplayer style="audiobooks nolistbutton nopn"]
</div>`  This seems to work how you would expect. The only problem left where ever I place the CSS in the style sheet it is effect my menu mark styling.

Comment: Hey Dave. Yes that update was correct. You were placing the html inside a class="" which will break your code. Now I think it must be a similar issue with how you are placing the css inside your css file. Have you tried the very bottom? You don't want the clearfix inside any existing code.